# Is there any limit to how many times an aircraft evacuation slide may be deployed?

Tags: safety, airline-operations, commercial-aviation

I've seen multiple videos online of evacuation slide tests and they all tend to be almost violent as they are very fast and loud, but I can't help thinking that it must put a lot of force on those seams when they inflate and along with that the material. Is there any **limit to how many times these may be deployed** before they must be retired?

Comment: must be Overhauled Every 3 Years to be Airworthy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The slide has to be removed from the aircraft completely (generally) and sent back to it's manufacturer to be inspected and repacked, but yes, it can be reused.

[This article talks about it in more detail.](http://www.gadling.com/2010/08/16/ask-gadling-does-it-really-cost-25-000-to-repack-an-airplane-e/)

As a far as "how many times", I would assume until it breaks ;).  Though honestly, I doubt a slide would ever be deployed more than once, maybe twice in it's life span.

Comment: How about if it has been used as a liferaft (exposed to salt water, etc.)? If the plane itself is a writeoff, would a reconditioned/repacked slide be accepted by the FAA, etc. for use in a new plane? Could there be hidden damage from heat (fire) that they wouldn't want to risk that? If a slide is usable as a raft, I would imagine they could remove the emergency beacon and sell it for whitewater rafting use!

Comment: If it doesn't pass inspection then it isn't reused (yeah, kind of a vague response, I know.  But they don't really talk about their inspection criteria in anything I read.)  It would be interesting if they sold them for different purposes though, that could be an interesting rafting experience!

Comment: @phil: do whitewater rafters commonly use defective substandard equipment designed for other purposes and rejected as unfit for use?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Commonly?  Nope.  But I've met plenty of uncommon folks that  are willing to try just about anything once ;).  The real question is if any company that makes them would be willing to put up with the liability...  My guess is no.